# Is there a country with a bipartisan Parliament formed in a proportional election?

Tags: parliament, democracy, proportional-representation, whipping

An idea of a bipartisan Parliament formed in a proportional election seems quite interesting to me. On one hand, in a proportional system, we vote for a party, knowing which ideas it would go forward with. On the other hand, the bipartisan system is always overburdened by ideological unlikeness within both parties. Therefore, when a vote is cast, no one could be sure it would get the candidate of the ideology the voter had in mind on the party list. It seems like such a Parliament would need a highly **machiavellian** Whip.

Is there such a Parliament? If so, am I right to think that it hinges on the Whips?

Comment: By "bipartisan", do you mean "having two parties"? I ask because the word is typically used to indicate that the two parties _agree_ on something, not that two parties _exist_. Indeed, a quick search for a definition gives: "involving the agreement or cooperation of two political parties that usually oppose each other's policies."

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff right, sorry. I reckon the "two-party system" to be a better use of words.

Comment: Malta could be an interesting example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there such a Parliament?

There's lots of them. The one that pops to mind best is Belgium; the [2019 general election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_Belgian_federal_election) returned a parliament that's heavily divided; the largest party has 25 seats with 76 needed for a majority:

| Party | Leader | % | Seats | ± |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N-VA | Bart De Wever | 16.03% | 25 | -8 |
| VB | Tom Van Grieken | 11.95% | 18 | +15 |
| PS | Elio Di Rupo | 9.46% | 20 | -3 |
| CD&V | Wouter Beke | 8.89% | 12 | -6 |
| PVDA-PTB | Peter Mertens | 8.62% | 12 | +10 |
| Open Vld | Gwendolyn Rutten | 8.54% | 12 | -2 |
| MR | Charles Michel | 7.56% | 14 | -6 |
| sp.a | John Crombez | 6.71% | 9 | -4 |
| ECOLO | Jean-Marc Nollet & Zakia Khattabi | 6.14% | 13 | +7 |
| Groen | Meyrem Almaci | 6.10% | 8 | +2 |
| cdH | Maxime Prévot | 3.70% | 5 | -4 |
| DéFI | Olivier Maingain | 2.22% | 2 | 0 |

A government has formed and fallen since then, but the [incumbent government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Croo_Government) currently consists of a coalition of 7 different parties within Parliament:

> Member parties
>
> Open Vld (Flemish)
> MR (Francophone)
> sp.a (Flemish)
> PS (Francophone)
> CD&V (Flemish)
> Ecolo (Francophone)
> Groen (Flemish)

So yeah, not so much **bi**partisan as...**sept**-partisan?

> If so, am I right to think that it hinges on the Whips?

Eh, not so much. Whips exist to keep individual Members of Parliament in line and prevent them from deviating from Party policy. In cases like this, the far more major problem is for major coalition partners keeping the minor coalition partners in line and preventing them from deviating from coalition policy. So it's more a problem for the party leaders and their aides and so on, rather than the whips (who really only deal with members of their own party and **at most** the other party's whips).

Just want to address this:

> On the other hand, the bipartisan system is always overburdened by ideological unlikeness within both parties.

This is not a burden, it is a feature.

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor accepted this answer so you must be onto something but isn't that the exact opposite of what was being asked? Belgium is a typical case of political fragmentation (not only due to the voting system, admittedly) but it doesn't seem especially functional or successful so I am not sure what it shows.

Comment: @Relaxed hmm, I might have rushed with pushing that tick, true. Yet, Dan Scally answered my second question (do you agree with them on whips in such a system?). Plus, I've never had much knowledge of Belgium's system (living outside of EU). I saw your comment on Malta. If you turn it into an answer, I would love to read. I am sorry for being clumsy with accepting and tossing the ticks around :(.

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor I don't know much about Malta, just that it has STV (a form of proportional voting that could easily accommodate more than two parties or even lead to fragmentation) but a rather stable two-party system.

Comment: @Relaxed I may have misread the question, but after re-reading it a couple times I don't read it any differently. The use of the word "bipartisan" I took to be just meaning "government" bloc in Parliament consists of more than one political party. I disagree wholeheartedly that Belgium's system of government is remotely dysfunctional or unsuccessful; quite the contrary, it's a marked improvement over most country's allocation of the majority of power to a single group. Regardless, the question was "does this exist?" not "is it any good?"

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor - If I misread your question and this answer is actually no good, my apologies. I'm more than happy to either edit or scrap it if it's not actually what you meant - but perhaps some clarification in that case, because I can't actually see where I've misread.

Comment: @DanScally Most countries have coalitions (even the US but it happens intra-party not between political parties), *especially* countries with PR so this interpretation of the question didn't make sense to me. I read it as meaning “only two parties” as that's often thought to result from plurality voting.

Comment: @Relaxed Yes, I agree that the commonality of multi-party government makes it a bit unusual; but as I say I couldn't see another reading that made sense. Like I say, if Zhiltsoff comes back and says it's not what they meant then I can just delete the answer, no problem.

Comment: Regarding the Belgium political system, you're right that it goes beyond the question and there would be a lot to discuss. I was just reacting to the notion that any of this was “a feature”. When you know a little bit about Belgium's government, it does not seem especially inclusive or broad-based but it seems harder to reach decisions or build coalition than in most places. So if the point was to highlight a stable multiparty parliamentary democracy, this is not the most obvious example, that's all. OTOH, the country still basically functions.

Comment: The OP commented under the question that “two-party system” might be a better word. This makes sense to me: is there a two-party system that's not enforced or maintained through the voting system (as opposed to more fragmented party system typical of PR on the one hand and two-party systems in FPTP countries on the other)? That's why I mentioned Malta.

Comment: @DanScally no, your answer is very interesting. I see no reason to scrap an answer just because there's a(n arguably) better example.Sorry for taking some time to comment back.